# How to set properly a zip programme with odfWeave?

Tags: r, zip, odfweave

I work with R 3.1.1 64 bits /Windows 8.1./7-zip 64 bits
I have tried since many days to make odfWeave working, but without success.
I have tried different odfWeaveControl options (see below) but still get that error message from R.
Any clue would be much appreciated.
Charles

```
Error unzipping file
In addition: Warning message: running command 'C:\Programmes\7-Zip\7z x -tzip "example01_in.odt" -yr' had status 127

odfctrl <- odfWeaveControl(zipCmd = c("C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z a -tzip $$file$$ .", "C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z x -tzip $$file$$"))

odfctrl <- odfWeaveControl(zipCmd = c("C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z -r $$file$$ .", "C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z -o $$file$$"))

odfctrl <- odfWeaveControl(zipCmd = c("C:/Program Files/7-zip/7z a -tzip $$file$$","C:/Program Files/7-zip/7z x $$file$$ -aoa")) 

odfctrl <- odfWeaveControl(zipCmd = c("C:/Program Files/7-zip/7z a -tzip $$file$$ .", "C:/Program Files/7-zip/7z x -tzip $$file$$")) 

odfctrl <- odfWeaveControl(zipCmd = c("C:\\Programmes\\7-Zip\\7z a -tzip $$file$$ . -r", "C:\\Programmes\\7-Zip\\7z x -tzip $$file$$ -yr"))

odfWeave("example01_in.odt", "example01.odt", control = odfctrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but maybe this post helps:

[Create zip file: error running command " " had status 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129681/create-zip-file-error-running-command-had-status-127)

Don't know if odfWeave works with zip as `utils::zip` does, but that's clearly a related problem