# Create zip file: error running command " " had status 127

Tags: r, zip

I am trying to create a zip file from multiple files using the `zip` function in r, but I keep getting this error message: 
running command '"zip" -r9X "data.zip" "dt1.txt" "dt2.txt" ' had status 127.

How can I avoid that?

```
setwd()
dt1 <- sample(1:100, 10)
dt2 <- sample(100:200, 10)
write(dt1, "dt1.txt")
write(dt2, "dt2.txt")

zip('data.zip', files =c('dt1.txt', 
                         'dt2.txt'))
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that status 127 means that the command was not found (the zip command in this case).

Answer (score 25):

Here is how I solved this problem on my Windows 7 computer:

1. Install `Rtools` from [HERE](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools).
2. Locate the folder that `Rtools` is installed. In my case it is at `C:\Rtools`.
3. Add `C:\Rtools\bin` path to the system path.

Adding `C:\Rtools\bin` to the system path:

1. Go to `Control Panel >> System and Security >> System`
2. Go to `Advanced System Settings`
3. Open `Advanced` tab
4. Click `Environmental Variables...` button
5. Select `Path` variable and click `Edit` button
6. If there is nothing as a "Variable Value" you can simply write `C:\Rtools\bin`. If there is already a value, then add `;C:\Rtools\bin` to the end of it.
7. Click OK, OK...
8. Restart R, it should work.

I hope this helps. I found the solution [HERE](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/Introduction.pdf).

Comment: not working for me, running Windows... I still get "status 127" when trying to run `system("SET PATH")`

Comment: Had the same issue, but in my case I needed to add the following to the system path: `C:\RBuildTools\3.3\bin;C:\RBuildTools\3.3\gcc-4.6.3\bin`

Comment: it looks like Rtools now sets the system path when installing Rtools.exe (at least on Windows)

Comment: This did not work for me -- added both the paths mentioned by @phiver & a `Sys.getenv("PATH")` confirms that the paths were added to the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem by removing the write-protection on `~/Users/<NAME>/Documents/R/win-library`.

Comment: at which step? before rtools is installed?