# Downloading a pdf using RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

What I am trying to do with `RSelenium` package is,

Step:1 Access a website - My own electric utility provider

Step:2 Access my account by explicitly providing my username and password (That's the reason I am unable to share the code)

Step:3 I click ***'VIEW MY BILL'***.
The bill is displayed in **pdf** format.

Is there a way to download that file and save to specific folder?
When I used `download.file()` command, it does not save the document, rather I get a 3KB pdf file that I am not able to open. Adobe Reader says that there is an error reading the document.

Possible method that I tried:
1. Right clicking, Pressing down arrow four times and then get to **'SAVE PAGE AS'** click Enter.

But then it pops a dialog box asking for file name and location and I am not able to enter those details via RSelenium and save the file.

Example code: Some random PDF found online.

```
url<- "http://www.immigrationpolicy.org/sites/default/files/docs/how_us_immig_system_works.pdf"

setwd("C:/Users/king/Desktop/bill")
library(RSelenium)
library(downloader)
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
```

Comment: Interesting question.  Can you provide a minimal working example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on continuous research.

Firstly check whether [Rtools is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129681/create-zip-file-error-running-command-had-status-127) (Found the answer using this link)

Then updated my program

```
cprof<-makeFirefoxProfile(list(
  "pdfjs.disabled"=TRUE,
  "plugin.scan.plid.all" = FALSE,
  "plugin.scan.Acrobat" = "99.0",
  "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"='application/pdf',
  ))
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities=cprof)
```

Trying still to change the download folder which I am not able to find yet. I found the answer from [THIS link](http://yizeng.me/2014/05/23/download-pdf-files-automatically-in-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: The above code worked only for the example in the question. When I tried the code in my actual application, the pdf file was autodownloaded as `.aspx` file.

But then tried renaming the file as filename.pdf it worked. I renamed the downloaded file as .pdf.