# Download Excel Files with RSelenium

Tags: r, excel, rselenium

I need to download an excel-file from a database (the reason that I cannot provide code). I'm able to click on the download icon using `RSelenium`.  What happens next is that the usual dialogue-window opens asking me if I want to save the file or open it. How can I suppress this message and download the file into a folder?

I have found a similar question regarding pdf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476422/downloading-a-pdf-using-rselenium). The answer suggests it should be possible by specifying of the `extraCapabilities`:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", 
                  browserName = "firefox",
                  extraCapabilities = someCapabilities,
                  port = 4444)
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to set `extraCapabilities` correctly.

Can somebody hint me in a direction? Thanks for help.

**Edit**

I'm aware of the solution provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/192498/skipping-the-download-dialog-in-firefox) and hope to be able to use the `extraCapabilities`-Approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
library(RSelenium)
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = makeFirefoxProfile(list(
  "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
))
remDr$open()
url <- "http://www.iwh-halle.de/e/fdz/IntBankLib/data/downloads/databases.xlsx"
remDr$navigate(url)
file.exists(file.path("~/Downloads/", basename(url)))
# [1] TRUE
```

Note that the [content type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields) has to match:

```
library(httr)
HEAD(url)$headers$`content-type`
# [1] "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

Although you should be able to use wildcards like `*`.

Comment: the `makeFirefoxProfile(...)` command returns an error: 

Error in file(tmpfile, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"zip" -r9Xjq "C:\Users\rockscience\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoPhjUb\file31028ad12f9.zip" "C:\Users\rockscience\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoPhjUb/firefoxprofile/prefs.js" ' had status 127 
2: In file(tmpfile, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\rockscience\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoPhjUb\file31028ad12f9.zip': No such file or directory

Comment: maybe because I run selenium in a docker?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.