# Download word document in local folder using Rselenium

Tags: selenium, rselenium

I am using R selenium to navigate through a website and eventually click a button that opens a dialog window to download the file. However, I want the file to automatically save in a different local folder.

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679950/download-excel-files-with-rselenium) question.

Instead of using `remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "firefox")` I have tried

`remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = makeFirefoxProfile(list(
  "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
))`, but this gave an error that some local folder does not exist.

Note that I have no prior knowledge of Selenium and am quite new to programming.

All help welcome!

EDIT: because it it concerns a .docx file the correct MIME type appears to be: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`. So I tried the following:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = makeFirefoxProfile(list(
  "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
```

))

but this gave following error:

```
Error in file(tmpfile, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"zip" -r9Xjq       "C:\Users\PiKr\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpApt5uQ\file19006f62c60.zip" "C:\Users\PiKr\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpApt5uQ/firefoxprofile/prefs.js" ' had status 127 
2: In file(tmpfile, "rb") :
 cannot open file 'C:\Users\PiKr\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpApt5uQ\file19006f62c60.zip': No such file or directory
```

Comment: you should use proper `MIME-type` for the file you want to download. Choose required from http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php and replace `"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"` with, for example, `"application/msword"` in case of `.doc` file

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found the correct MIME-type but still get an error (see edit in my post).

Comment: Yeah.. I just suggest you to edit your code with correct `MIME` type. I hardly can help you with your problem as I know how to deal with it in `Python`, but have no idea about `R` :)) Obviously, somewhere in your code interpreter tries to open `C:\Users\PiKr\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpApt5uQ\file19006f62c60.zip` file, but cannot find it.

Comment: I guess you must install the Rtools from the [website](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and install the rtools before your proceed running the above program. Zipping action needs Rtools to perform. (Referring to the error 1)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you must install the Rtools from the [website](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and install the rtools before your proceed running the above program. Zipping action needs Rtools to perform. (Referring to the error 1)

Add the path to environment variable, if it doesn't add automatically

Comment: Adding the path on windows is no longer by default checked when installing RTools. Checking it is essential and solved my same issue as the question after reinstalling Rtools. Thanks.