# Zipping a file using R

Tags: r, zip

Im trying to zip a file in R that is in a folder on my PC
My code is below

```
setwd('C:/temp')
zip(zipfile = 'testZip', files = 'test.txt')
```

Im getting the error

> Warning message: running command '"zip" -r9X "testZip" "test.txt" '
>   had status 127

I found on this site an answer that involves messing with the windows envoirnment: [Create zip file: error running command " " had status 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129681/create-zip-file-error-running-command-had-status-127)

However when i try to install Rtools i get the error

> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘rtools’ is not available (for
>   R version 3.2.0)

I am restricted to being able to zip the file as either `7zip` or `.zip`

The version of R i have is: `R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is more of a comment, but I don't have enough rep to do that.

Did you type in `install.packages("rtools")`? I ask because your warning says `rtools`. If that is the case try `install.packages("Rtools")`. Not capitalizing the R makes a difference in R. 
Unfortunately I'm not at my computer so I can't test this. If this doesn't work let me know and I'll update my answer.

EDIT: After some more research it looks like install.packages() doesn't work for Rtools.  You have to manually download it from online.  Here's a link to an Rtools wiki on github that tells you how to download Rtools: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows

Comment: Hi @Chase Grimm i tried but got the error `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)`

Comment: I edited my answer, the provided link provides a walk-through to install Rtools.