# R package build fails on zip, but Rtools are installed

Tags: r, windows, package

This question is very related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941838/r-build-package-fails-on-zip#), but for some small differences.

I am trying to build a package to a binary .zip file on windows.

```
> devtools::build(binary = TRUE, args = c('--library="H:pathtolibrary"', '--preclean'))
"w:/R/R/R-33~1SQ.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL "R:\path" --build --library="H:pathtolibrary" --preclean 

* installing *source* package 'packagename' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* MD5 sums
Warning: running command '"zip" -r9Xq "R:/path" packagename' had status 127
running 'zip' failed
* DONE (independeR)
[1] "R:/path"
```

In other questions I found that the status 127 corresponds to the command 'zip' not existing. However, I do have Rtools installed. Because I don't have admin rights on the pc, and my user settings get reset on startup, the `Rtools/bin/` directory is not in my PATH at startup, but even when I add it back, confirming it is actually there in CMD, R still gives this status 127.

```
C:\Users\jdubbeldam>path
PATH=C:/otherstuff;H:/Documents/Rtools/bin
```

And running `zip` on CMD doesn't complain either.

```
C:\Users\jdubbeldam>zip
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008). Usage:
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
  The default action is to add or replace zipfile entries from list, which
  can include the special name - to compress standard input.
  If zipfile and list are omitted, zip compresses stdin to stdout.
  -f   freshen: only changed files  -u   update: only changed or new files
  -d   delete entries in zipfile    -m   move into zipfile (delete OS files)
  -r   recurse into directories     -j   junk (don't record) directory names
  -0   store only                   -l   convert LF to CR LF (-ll CR LF to LF)
  -1   compress faster              -9   compress better
  -q   quiet operation              -v   verbose operation/print version info
  -c   add one-line comments        -z   add zipfile comment
  -@   read names from stdin        -o   make zipfile as old as latest entry
  -x   exclude the following names  -i   include only the following names
  -F   fix zipfile (-FF try harder) -D   do not add directory entries
  -A   adjust self-extracting exe   -J   junk zipfile prefix (unzipsfx)
  -T   test zipfile integrity       -X   eXclude eXtra file attributes
  -!   use privileges (if granted) to obtain all aspects of WinNT security
  -$   include volume label         -S   include system and hidden files
  -e   encrypt                      -n   don't compress these suffixes
  -h2  show more help
```

None of the solutions given in the linked question help in this case.

Does R use a different PATH variable internally with CMD commands run from R code?

Is there any way to manually zip the output of `devtools::build(binary = T)`?