# zipping very many files in r

Tags: r, csv, zip, large-data-volumes

I have 7300 *.csv files in a temp directory.  I want to zip these into a zip archive in R.  I'm using the following code, which is taking FOREVER.  Is there a way to do this faster, short of exiting R and using the WinZip program?

```
fileListing       = list.files( pattern = '*.csv' )
outZipFileName    = gsub( '.zip', '_TZflts.zip', zipName )
sapply(seq_along( fileListing),function(ii) zip( outZipFileName, fileListing[ii] ) )
```

Another problem is that the zip process in the code spawns tons of garbage files, besides the zip file and its csv contents.

Thank you.

BSL

Comment: you dont need to loop through the files.. you can add them all in one `zip` call. Oh actually, have I misunderstood.. do you want a separate zip files for each csv, or all csv's in one zip?

Comment: No.  One zip archive containing 7300 csv files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to loop through the files, `zip` can take a vector of the files to be zipped: this should speed things up. From `?zip`

> files is : 'A character vector of recorded filepaths to be included.'

Example

```
# write some files to be zipped
for(i in 1:10) write.csv(mtcars, paste0("SOtemp", i, ".csv"))

# zip
zip("SOzip", files=list.files(pattern="SOtemp\\d"))

# remove files from this example
# file.remove(c("SOzip.zip", list.files(pattern="SOtemp\\d")))
```

Comment: Tried it with your command.  Received warning message, 'running command '"zip" -r9X ', followed by a listing of all 7300 csv files.  No zip file was created.

Comment: did the small example in my answer work? If not, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129681/create-zip-file-error-running-command-had-status-127 is probably useful (although i would try it again straight after installing rtools, before setting paths etc)

Comment: okay, I just tried it on a windows partition and I got the same message as you. I then followed the steps (including setting the path)  in [HBat's amswer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129681/create-zip-file-error-running-command-had-status-127?answertab=votes#tab-top) and it now works.

Comment: Will try your link.  I found that zip( 'filename.zip', files=fileListing[1 : 1100] ) worked without error.  So, I infer that there is a limit to the number of files that R can zip at once (either total bytes to zip or limit on total files).  I'm going to just add 1000 files at a time.