# Why do I get a system status error of 127 when I run wget in R?

Tags: r, ftp, system-error

I am trying to run a script to download some weather data from a NOAA ftp site. 
When I attempt to run the following command:

```
system("wget ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/2016/999999-54856-2016.gz")
```

it returns status 127, which as I understand simply means the command will not run. 
This link on the other hand, seems to be working well and downloads the zip folder when I ran it in the browser. 
I read online about adding the path 'C:\Rtools\bin' from this link: [Create zip file: error running command " " had status 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129681/create-zip-file-error-running-command-had-status-127) but that doesn't seem to work either. 
I'm wondering if this might be a permissions issue or other security setting preventing me from invoking system commands. 
Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Windows. wget is a Unix/Linux program. You can just call download.file to download from within R:

```
download.file("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/2016/999999-54856-2016.gz",
              "999999-54856-2016.gz", mode="wb")
```

The `mode="wb"` is important for downloading binary files on Windows.